# Running python program using php

Tags: php, python-2.7

Can we run python programs on server using php,?If yes how? I am using nltk and bs4 packages.I tried with exec and escapeshellarg() for the same. But empty page is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Yes, you can run any command from PHP level. Please provide your non-working code (what you have tried), so we can try to help you with it. In general `shell_exec()` should help here. Also the question is if it's acceptable practice to do so.

Comment: This is the php code <?php
 $output = array();
 $result = exec('yy.py');
 $output = json_decode($result);
 echo $output;
 ?>

Comment: This is the python script I want to run: #!C:\Python27 env python
import json
from senti_classifier import senti_classifier
sentences = ['The movie was the worst movie.It was the worst acting by the actors']pos_score, neg_score = senti_classifier.polarity_scores(sentences)
print pos_score
json.dumps(pos_score)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can run by using exec command

Suppose you have you python program in script.py file. than you can do this.

```
<?php    
 echo exec('python script.py');
?>
```